# How to take string as input using pointers without declaration of variable for string?

Tags: c, pointers, char

[image][image][image][image]
char *p="This is anonymous string literal";

Doing this I can access this string easily but tell me that how can I get string literal from user using this `p` pointer without declaring the other variable for string. Check my images from button to top.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you cannot. You need to allocate sufficient storage in RAM for your program to hold your string. Whilst I am not an expert on C I'd even say that manipulating that string is haphazard.

Comment: The question is quite unclear. Please explain better or show an example of (possible incorrect) code that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah , I know I almost can not manipulate but at least I could save memory for third variable. I just wanna know if there is any way of dealing my questions.

Comment: Data cannot be stored in thin air, it has to be stored in valid memory. Also, unrelated to your question, whoever taught you to use `gets` should not be used as a source of learning.

Answer (score 0):

A string literal declares a **`const`** character array. That means that any try to change the characters through the `p` pointer would invoke Undefined Behaviour (the hell for C programmers...).

To be able to read a *string* from the user (note, not a *literal* one), you must either declare a character array, or allocate one with `malloc` and friends.

Examples:

```
char str[80];
char *p = str;  // Ok, you can do what you want with 79 charactes (last should be null)
```

or

```
char *p = malloc(80); // again 80 characters to play with
...
free(p);   // but you are responsable for releasing allocated memory when done
```

Comment: please check out my images too.

Comment: @AnupAdhikari: 1/ you should not post images but only provide code as **test**. 2/ `gets` is deprecated for ages because it is a known recipe for writing past end of the passed character array - the recommended function is `fgets`. 3/ my answer is still relevant: you can only use `gets` (or better `fgets`) with an *existing* array - so after `char str[80]; char *p = str;`, you may use `gets(ptr)` (or better (fgets(ptr, sizeof(str), stdin);`)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the size of your string requires memory allocation.

Maybe you could just use a pointer to this string in your program and change the target of the pointer.
That may not answer your question but it can be interesting.

```
char *str = "My string";
char *str2 = "My string 2";
char **ptr = &str;

printf("%s\n", *ptr);
ptr = &str2;
printf("%s\n", *ptr);
```

### Edit

From gets() documentation:

> str − This is the pointer to an array of chars where the C string is stored

Means that the pointer passed as parameters of gets() must already have allocated memory, you could try:

```
char p[50];
// instead of
char *p; // No memory allocated to put user input in
```

That's why you got a segfault (with memory observation tools like valgrind you'll see errors on all compilers).

Also printf() is not flushing the output without a carriage return (\n), you could try:

```
printf("No carriage return");
fflush(stdout); // Force stdout update
```

Comment: yeah it is interesting but please check out my images too.